# Eclipse RCP vs Eclipse PDE

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

What is difference between a eclipse plugin environment and eclipse rcp plugin?

I am confussed that when you launch any eclipse plugin as eclipse application , it is nothing but you are running a rcp application.

Please help me in correcting both the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDE is the plugin *development* environment, which you use to write new plugins for other Eclipse users. It is part of the Eclipse standard IDE.

When those new plugins are deployed to a user afterwards, then he is running an RCP application. That RCP application typically contains way less plugins, and typically does not contain the PDE anymore.

Answer (score -5):

Eclipse Applications follow the following formula

Eclipse App = Plugins + Platform
Eclipse App = PDE + RCP

Eclipse ide is an eclipse of an Eclipse Applications.

RCP is the bundling platform on top of which ur plugins r installed and executed.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer contradicts the accepted answer, so please provide sources to prove your statement. While editing it would be good if you can avoid chatting abbreviations ("ur", "r").